# Criando tabela de logs generica para diversas models Django

Tags: json, postgresql, django, log

Eu tenho 30 models. Cada uma delas contem informações de uma calculadora e cada registro são informações de sub calculadoras. Preciso criar uma tabela de logs de cada calculo feito pelo usuário.

Atualmente eu estou salvando o JSON do que o cara manda e salvando também o resultado em JSON. Pois cada calculadora possui campos diferentes e resultados diferentes (alguns são listas, outros variáveis e outros dicionários).

Existe uma forma melhor de fazer isso? O problema que estou enfrentando é que se eu quiser tirar relatórios/métricas de todos os dados eu teria que criar um script para obter e transformar (de cada calculo feito por usuario). Coisa que se eu tivesse salvando tudo em uma model seria mais fácil (com o Django).

O problema é que eu teria que criar então + 30 models. Ou então eu teria que criar centenas de campos que todas as calculadoras possuem e também campos com todos os resultados possíveis. Fica um pouco confuso imaginar isso.

Alguem poderia me dar uma dica diante esse cenário?

Comment: Uma sugestão seria utilizar o campo de tipo jsonb no postgres, o django possui mapeamento para ele. Dessa forma você poderia ter um model com algumas colunas que seriam padrão para todos e um campo jsonb com as informações específicas de cada calculadora.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo a utilização da Lib [Django Activity Stream](https://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/streams.html).

É possível criar os logs de forma dinâmica, com informações especificas sobre **ator**, **ação** e **alvo da ação**.